# Xamarin.Forms: Not appearing OxyPlot Pie Chart

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, oxyplot

Good Day everyone. I'm creating a Xamarin.Forms Portable Application and I want to display there a Chart using a OxyPlot.

I followed a documentation in [here](http://docs.oxyplot.org/en/latest/getting-started/hello-xamarin-forms.html#create-the-project) about OxyPlot. But I still kinda confuse. Can you please look at the process I followed and check if what I did was right? These are just based on my own understanding.

Here's what I did :

1. Update the Xamarin.Forms NuGet packages to the latest version.
2. Add the OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms NuGet package in both the portable and platform specific projects.
3. I initialize the OxyPlot renderers by adding **OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.PlotViewRenderer.Init();** just after the Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init() in my MainActivity.cs
4. In the portable app project, I added this plot view to my App.cs.

   ```
   public App()
   {
       this.MainPage = new ContentPage
       {
       Content = new PlotView
       {
       Model = new PlotModel { Title = "Hello, Forms!" },
       VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
       HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
           },
       };
   }
   ```
5. In my XAML page, I added this namespace declaration :

> xmlns:oxy="clr-namespace:OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms;assembly=OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms"

6. Then I added this on the same page.

   ```
    <oxy:PlotView Model="{Binding Model1}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
   ```

   Here's the code of the whole SalesPage.xaml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        xmlns:oxy="clr-namespace:OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms;assembly=OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms"
        xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:XamarinFormsDemo.ViewModels;assembly=XamarinFormsDemo"
        x:Class="XamarinFormsDemo.Views.SalesPage"
        BackgroundImage="bg3.jpg"
        Title="Sales Page">



     <ContentPage.BindingContext>
       <ViewModels:SalesVM/>
     </ContentPage.BindingContext>


       <oxy:PlotView Model="{Binding Model1}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>


   </ContentPage>
   ```
7. After that, I tried to call my view model that contains the content of my chart named **PiewViewModel.cs**

   ```
   using OxyPlot;
   using OxyPlot.Series;

   namespace ExampleLibrary
   {

       public class PieViewModel
       {
           private PlotModel modelP1;
           public PieViewModel()
       {
           modelP1 = new PlotModel { Title = "Pie Sample1" };

           dynamic seriesP1 = new PieSeries { StrokeThickness = 2.0,     InsideLabelPosition = 0.8, AngleSpan = 360, StartAngle = 0 };

           seriesP1.Slices.Add(new PieSlice("Africa", 1030) { IsExploded = false, Fill = OxyColors.PaleVioletRed });
           seriesP1.Slices.Add(new PieSlice("Americas", 929) { IsExploded = true });
           seriesP1.Slices.Add(new PieSlice("Asia", 4157) { IsExploded = true });
           seriesP1.Slices.Add(new PieSlice("Europe", 739) { IsExploded = true });
           seriesP1.Slices.Add(new PieSlice("Oceania", 35) { IsExploded = true });

           modelP1.Series.Add(seriesP1);

       }

       public PlotModel Model1
       {
           get { return modelP1; }
           set { modelP1 = value; }
       }
      }
    }
   ```
8. Here's my MainActivity.cs for Android

   ```
     using System;
     using Android.App;
     using Android.Content.PM;
     using Android.Runtime;
     using Android.Views;
     using Android.Widget;
     using Android.OS;
     using ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Droid;

     namespace XamarinFormsDemo.Droid
     {
         [Activity(Label = "XamarinFormsDemo", Icon = "@drawable/recordsicon", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
         public class MainActivity :           global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
         {
             protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
   {
       base.OnCreate(bundle);

       global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
       OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.PlotViewRenderer.Init();
       LoadApplication(new App());
       ImageCircleRenderer.Init();
             }
         }
     }
   ```

Can you please tell me what I've done wrong? The chart isn't appearing.  Any help to a newbie like me is highly appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: So is the result that no PieGraph is shown? or is there a `Title = "Hello, Forms!"` like the Run-Time created PlotView and you're hoping to see `Title = "Pie Sample1"` as per the Design-Time created PlotView with its associated PieViewModel binding?

Comment: @JeremyThompson there's nothing on the screen at all Sir.

Comment: Can you show us your `public class MainActivity : AndroidActivity` eg: https://github.com/oxyplot/documentation-examples/blob/master/HelloWorld/XamarinFormsApp1/XamarinFormsApp1/XamarinFormsApp1.Android/MainActivity.cs

Comment: @JeremyThompson I've already added it in my codes Sir. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your MainActivity class needs to derive from `AndroidActivity` not `FormsApplicationActivity`

Comment: @JeremyStephens I replaced it but nothing happened Sir? Have you checked my codes? Do you think my binding is correct? Thanks for answering Sir.

Comment: The MainActivity class is the only one that looks different from the demo sample. Why not download the sample and build that to confirm it works, then compare your to it and spot the differences.

Comment: but that's what I did? I don't know why it does not appear?